# Gronwall inequality for $\frac{d}{dt}u(t) \leq C_1u(t) + C_2\sqrt{u(t)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have the inequality
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t) \leq C_1u(t) + C_2\sqrt{u(t)}$$
for a positive function $u$. Is there a Gronwall inequality that I can use to write
$$u(t) \leq C_3u(0)?$$
or something similar. I definitely need something where the right hand side is $u(0) \times \text{something}$.

Comment: No chance. Already $u'\leqslant Cu$ with $C\gt0$ does not imply that $u$ is bounded. Or are you assuming that $C_1$ is negative?

Comment: I see. No, C_1 is positive.

Comment: Then solve $u'=C_1u$ and weep... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Íf $C_2 = 0$, the sharp inequality holds 
$$ u(t) \le u(0) e^{C_1 t} 
$$
and if $C_1 = 0$, there is the sharp inequality
$$
u(t) \le \left(\sqrt{u(0)} + \frac{C_2t}{2} \right)^2
= u(0) + C_2t\sqrt{u(0)} + \frac{C_2^2t^2}{4}
$$
so you cannot expect an estimate like "$u(t) \le u(0) \cdot K(t)$" for some function $K(t)$.

In the general case, you can estimate
$$
\frac{d}{dt} u \le C_1u + C_2\sqrt{u} \le (C_1 + \delta)u + \frac{C_2^2}{4 \delta}
$$
for any $\delta > 0$, leading to the estimate
$$
u(t) \le \left( u(0) + \frac{C_2^2}{4 \delta (C_1 + \delta)} \right) e^{(C_1 + \delta)t} - \frac{C_2^2}{4 \delta (C_1 + \delta)}  .
$$ 
This does not contain an explicit factor $u(0)$, and this cannot be expected. But you could make this more explicit by minimizing the right hand side wrt. $\delta$.